# jpa sometimes return String instead of Date

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa

I have a native query in my code, it return a date from a mysql table using a group by with rollup:

```
SELECT      
    fecha,      
    q1.id_articulo,      
    a.nombre,      
    [...]
FROM (       
    SELECT
        DATE(mm.ts) AS fecha,
        au.id_articulo AS id_articulo,  
        mm.tipo_mercaderia_movimiento
        [...]       
    FROM mercaderia_movimiento mm       
    LEFT JOIN articulo_unidad au ON mm.id_articulo_unidad=au.id_articulo_unidad       
    WHERE 
        mm.id_articulo_unidad IS NOT NULL       
        AND tipo_mercaderia_movimiento IN ('IND','OUTD')       
        AND au.id_articulo=1611       
        AND DATE(mm.ts) BETWEEN '2013-11-30 00:00:00' AND '2014-05-30 00:00:00'
        AND mm.id_deposito=2
    GROUP BY DATE(mm.ts),mm.tipo_mercaderia_movimiento, au.id_articulo) q1     
LEFT JOIN articulo a ON q1.id_articulo=a.id_articulo     
GROUP BY fecha, q1.id_articulo WITH ROLLUP
```

as you can see in the subquery q1 I take "mm.ts", a timestamp, and do a DATE() on it, so the corresponding datataype is surely a Date, in the top query I simply take the field (fecha), so theres no change in the datatype. 
Using "with rollup" generate a resulting table like this:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+----
| fecha      | id_articulo | nombre                              | ...
+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+----
| 2014-05-30 |        1611 | LOMO MAS DE 5 - LOMO + 5 L. C/C IWP | ...
| 2014-05-30 |        NULL | LOMO MAS DE 5 - LOMO + 5 L. C/C IWP | ...
| NULL       |        NULL | LOMO MAS DE 5 - LOMO + 5 L. C/C IWP | ...
+------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+----
```

so fecha is Date or null. Being sure of that I have in my code this line:

```
Date fecha = row[0]!=null ? (Date) row[0] : null;
```

When I execute the query using jpa native query I sometimes get a

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

I'm pretty sure the problem exists only if the table contains only one value of fecha and null (like the example above) and not if I have more than one.

Is this problem known? What can I do to be sure that fecha is returned as Date?

Thank you!

Comment: `Date fecha = row[0]!=null ? (Date) row[0] : null;` does not make any sense. `null` can be cast to any type, so `Date fecha = (Date) row[0]` the same.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?